# Checkbox does not work with keys in React

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a component where there are checkboxes. Using map I need to use keys in React. I created function that generates unique keys. But after that my checkboxes stop working properly. I cannot click some of them, some styles dissapear. Why is that going on? I thought keys are just such stuff needed for giving a unique id for React.

```
// generating id

export function uid(): string {
  return (performance.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(16)).replace(/\./g, '');
}
```

```
// my component

export default function Table(props:ITable) {

  if (props.loader) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            {props.actions.map((element) =>
              element.onChangeAll &&
                <Checkbox
                  key={uid()}
                  indeterminate
                  onChange={element.onChangeAll}
                  label={element.label}
                  disabled={props.columns.every((el) => el.disabled)}
                />)}
          </th>
          {props.headers.map((header) =>
            <TableHeader
              key={uid()}
              header={header}
            />)}
          {props.actions.map((element) =>
            element.header &&
              <th key={uid()}>{element.header}</th>)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.columns.map((data) =>
          <tr
            className={classNames(
              data.checked ? 'row-active' : 'row',
              data.disabled && 'row-disabled'
            )}
            key={uid()}
          >
            <td>
              {props.actions.map((element) =>
                element.onChangeCheckbox &&
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={element.onChangeCheckbox}
                    disabled={data.disabled}
                    checked={data.checked}
                    id={data.id.toString()}
                    key={uid()}
                  />)}
            </td>
            {props.headers.map((header) =>
              <TableRow
                key={uid()}
                columns={data}
                header={header}
              />)}
            {props.actions.map((element) =>
              element.element &&
                  <td
                    key={uid()}
                    onClick={() => {
                      element.deleteRaw && element.deleteRaw(data.id);
                      element.openModal && element.openModal(data);
                    }}
                  >
                    {element.element}
                  </td>)}
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```